# Symfony : Redirect user when session is expired

Tags: symfony, event-listener

on my Symfony 6.3 application I set the `cookie_lifetime` to 3600, so the User session expire after one hour.

What I need is to catch the "expiration event" for redirect User automaticaly to login page.

I think I need to create a Event listener with the method `onKernelRequest()` but I'm not sure how to build it.

Someone can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tend to prefer using Event Subscribers ([as opposed to event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#listeners-or-subscribers)) for this sort of thing since they tend to require less configuration (e.g. *services.yaml*) to get working properly.

Here's a fairly bare-bones example of how this would look:

```
// src/EventSubscriber/SessionExpirationSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

use App\Exception\SessionExpiredException; // A custom exception you created.

class SessionExpirationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        // return the subscribed events, their methods and priorities
        // Priority value is a positive or negative integer which defaults to 0. The higher the number, the earlier the method is called
        // relative to other subscribers of that event.
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['checkSessionExpiration', -10],
            ],
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['handleSessionExpired', 0],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function checkSessionExpiration(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            // Skip checking sub-requests.
            return;
        }

        // Getting the expiration time as a Unix timestamp
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();
        $cookieCreated = $session->getMetadataBag()->getCreated();
        $cookieLifetime = $session->getMetadataBag()->getLifetime();
        $cookieExpiry = $cookieCreated + $cookieLifetime;

        if (time() > $cookieExpiry) {
            $session->invalidate();
            throw new SessionExpiredException();
        }
    }

    public function handleSessionExpired(ExceptionEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($event->getThrowable() instanceof SessionExpiredException) {
            $loginUrl = $this->router->generate('login'); // Or the name of whatever route you want to redirect to.
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($loginUrl));
        }
    }
}
```

### How it works

As far as wiring up your subscriber, from the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber):

> Your services.yaml file should already be setup to load services from the EventSubscriber directory. Symfony takes care of the rest.

- Now, when a `RequestEvent` is dispatched, the `checkSessionExpiration` method is called. Note that it skips checking anything for sub-requests.
- The [cookieExpiry time](https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html#session-idle-time-keep-alive) is checked and if it has expired, then a `SessionExpiredException` is thrown. Note: you'll have to create this exception yourself.
- An `ExceptionEvent` is dispatched which the subscriber also listens for and is handled by `handleSessionExpired`.
- `handleSessionExpired` checks for your custom `SessionExpiredException` and modifies the response of the event to redirect to the login page (or wherever you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check the following [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#defining-event-listeners-with-php-attributes).

Thanks to Attribute, you can create a new Class with following namespace and code:

```php
namespace App\EventListener;

#[AsEventListener(event: ExpirationEvent::class, method: 'onCustomEvent')]
final class MyListener
{
    public function onCustomEvent(ExpirationEvent $event): void
    {
        // ...
    }
```

You will just need to find the event dispatched when the cookie of the user expires (I didn't check if this is possible).